# Could my sprint unit be a scenario instead of a feature? (Gherkin terms)

Tags: agile, kanban, user-stories, jira, features

My team's Business Analyst and I have written some Gherkin files describing user stories of our new project.
As usual, a Gherkin file is composed of one feature, itself detailed through one or multiple scenarios.

The current step is to establish the different sprints (agile evolution) and their respective content.

Personally, I want those sprints to prioritise useful and tangible values for the end user.
That's why I think to consider a scenario as the unit of those sprints.

For instance, we would have:

- Sprint 1 dealing with first and second scenarios of Feature 1 + first from Feature 2.
- Sprint 2 dealing with second from Feature 2 + first from Feature 3.

You get the idea: a feature implementation could not be atomically implemented, but a scenario would.
This would allow to incrementally program several features during a same sprint while letting the possibility to fully complete one feature after N sprints.

I wonder how to handle Jira feeding.
Could one Kanban "ticket" represent an exact scenario of some feature or should it represent the whole feature instead?

Comment: In your example, when you complete the first and second scenario of Feature 1 and the first scenario of Feature 2, would that result in a 'potentially shippable product'?

Comment: Yes, of course, otherwise I wouldn't only pick them for the sprint.

Comment: In that case I would say this is a great approach!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'd like to say that this is a wonderful experiment. Please chronicle your experience and share it with the world.

> We are uncovering better ways of developing
>   software by doing it and helping others do it.

[*The Manifesto for Agile Software Development*](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

---

Jira doesn't have a concept of features, but it does have Epics. You could enter your features as epics and each scenario as a user story (linked to its parent epic). The concepts map reasonably well and this should give you the traceability you need.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's JIRA Epics that would fit your features and Stories could be your scenarios. You should play around with using epics, stories and sub-tasks to best suit your needs. 
I think the method you are describing would be a very good experiment to do - see what happens!